# file_exists in php is wrong ... or am I wrong?

Tags: php

So I have a directory such as:

```
Something
|_  Setup.php
|_  development.php
```

Inside of `Setup.php` I did the following:

```
if(file_exists('development.php')){
    // do something.
}
```

But the issue is that it never sees the `development.php` file, when I do an `else{}` statement to see if maybe I spelt it wrong it goes straight to the else statement.

How does this file **NOT** exist? It's spelt properly, am I missing something?

Comment: I'd suggest using a full filepath before `development.php` - where you code is running isn't necessarily where the server runs it, and using a full path means that you're both looking in the same place

Comment: may want to check the permissions set on `development.php`

Comment: Does `getcwd()` return what you expect? What does `glob("*")` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working directory is probably not what you think it is.

Try using the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'development.php')){
    // do something.
}
```

Your PHP file's parent directory will be substituted where `__DIR__` appears.